# Which Variables in these Questions are Free and Bound?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Simplify the following statements. Which variables are free and which are
bound? If the statement has no free variables, say whether it is true or
false.

(a) w ∈ {x ∈ R | 13 − 2x > c}.

(b) 4 ∈ {x ∈ R | 13 − 2x ∈ {y | y is a prime number}}. (It might make
this statement easier to read if we let P = {y | y is a prime number};
using this notation, we could rewrite the statement as 4 ∈ {x ∈ R |
13 − 2x ∈ P}.)

(c) 4 ∈ {x ∈{y | y is a prime number} |13 − 2x > 1}. , {y | y is a prime number} = P

Solutions:

(a) (w ∈ R) ∧ (13 − 2(4) > c) x us bound, c,w are free variablses

(b) (4 ∈ R) ∧  (13 − 2(4) ∈ P) bound variables x, y, no free variables TRUE

(4 ∈ R) ∧ (4 ¬∈ P) ∧ (13 − 2(4) > 1) bound variables x, y, no free varaibles  FALSE

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help understanding these solutions?

Comment: Also, [please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions given in the post are correct.